# bottom of screen address bar

Tags: java, android, android-studio, scrollview

I am trying to imitate the address bar in Chrome Dev Apk or the chrome:flags for android with just a EditText and a imgButton. I have tried many ways to do this such as with a scrollview but nothing is working. I have a removed the code for the scrollview and am wondering if you could tell me where to add the code to do this. Once done i will upload the .xml file. if you need the .java file just ask.

current xml layout

```
tools:context="com.equiware.mickeyt.equinox.MainActivity">


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/search_bar"
    style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.EditText"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/Transparent"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:hint="@string/search"
    android:imeOptions="normal|actionUnspecified|actionGo"
    android:singleLine="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/options_menu"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/webView"
    tools:textSize="12sp" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/options_menu"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ImageButton"

    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:onClick="showPopup"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/search_bar"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/webView"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_list"
    tools:ignore="OnClick" />

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="361dp"
    android:layout_height="526dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/search_bar"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

</WebView>
```